# Did Washington ever impose any sort of investment ban on Nazi germany?

Tags: united-states, nazi-germany, finance

There is archived coverage about multinational companies, headquartered in the US, that have had operations in Nazi Germany, like [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/national/daily/nov98/nazicars30.htm). While these multinationals appear to have received some public blowback, there does not appear to have been any red tape that prevented them from these operations. In a similar vein, I would like to explore what, if anything, was done on the financial front.

That is to say, has Washington ever imposed restrictions on US investors from allocating into German securities, blanket (nation-wide) or targeted (specific securities/sectors)?

Thank you

Comment: I would rule out the actual guy, pretty sure he was dead by then, but even the more likely options, does "Washington" refer to the US government or the US state of that name?

Comment: Until Germany invaded Poland I don't believe so. Sanctions on Japan were a result of their continuing their attacks on China.